# Passing props to component in another file redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to pass props to a component that lives in another file using redux. passing it in as a prop to the component isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated, just started learning Redux!

## Heading

```js
export class DisconnectedAllDogs extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='all-dogs'>
          <h1>Peter's Park</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          { this.props.dogs.map(dog => {
            return <DogCard  dog = {dog}/>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    dogs: state.dogs
  }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {

  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DisconnectedAllDogs)
```

```js
const DogCard = () => {
  return (
    <div class='dog-card'>
      <Link key={ this.props.dog.id }>{ this.props.dog.name }</Link>
    </div>
  )
}


export default DogCard
```

Comment: What happens when you `console.log` your props?

Comment: As @JulienD said, try to `console.log` your props, i.e, the dog object in your `DogCard` component. And, you've defined a functional component , so you don't need to use `this.props`, just use `props`.

Answer (score 0):

I think a variation on the second component (DogCard) as follow hopefully solve the issue you might be facing.

```
const DogCard = (props) => {
      return (
        <div class='dog-card'>
          <Link key={ props.dog.id }>{ props.dog.name }</Link>
        </div>
      )
    }


    export default DogCard
```

and about the other component I think you did an awesome job there. but in case you face an issue feel free to add a constructor as:

```
export class DisconnectedAllDogs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = null;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='all-dogs'>
          <h1>Peter's Park</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          { this.props.dogs.map(dog => {
            return <DogCard  dog = {dog}/>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    dogs: state.dogs
  }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {

  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DisconnectedAllDogs)
```

Really hope it was helpful...

Comment: Please let me know if ti helped or not so as to improve my answer to help